# How to remove Sender header when sending from another Gmail

Tags: gmail

I set up Gmail with an embarrassing username I created as a teenager which my friends and family use (let's call it `lolz@gmail.com`), then later created a serious e-mail account (`my.name@gmail.com`) which I use as alias via **`Send mail as`** feature from my `lolz@gmail.com`.

Recently I was shocked to discover that e-mails sent via my alias `my.name@gmail.com` had `lolz@gmail.com` in the `Sender` header.

The `Treat as an alias` option doesn't seem to have any effect on this.

Has anyone found a way to dispose of the `Sender` header?

**Edit**

Here you can see the Sender (and others) header. You can access it by clicking on the "details" arrow in mail detail (right top of the mail) and then "Show original".

Redacting colors meaning:

- blue: recipient (ok)
- pink: lolz@gmail.com (NOT ok)
- green: my.name@gmail.com (ok)

[image: Show original]

Comment: Add screen shot of what you call header, then tag me.

Comment: @DaniSpringer here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you canNOT.

**For security reasons the original gmail account (google domain) will always be shown**.

In your case the best thing to do would be to use your my.name@gmail.com account as your main account, create there an alias as lolz@gmail.com and have either email checked from that account or everything forwarded from your original lolz@gmail account to my.name@gmail.com.

[image: gmail settings]

From gmail help:

> Check email from other accounts with Gmail If you have multiple email
>   accounts, you can check them all in Gmail. Gmail’s Mail Fetcher
>   feature first imports all your old messages to Gmail and then
>   continues to bring in new messages sent to your other account. You can
>   add up to 5 accounts, including Gmail and other email providers.
>
> If you only want to get new emails brought into Gmail, try
>   auto-forwarding your mail instead.

This way when replying to friends and family will still get your lolz@gmail.com account (sender and reply path to my.name@gmail.com) and business associates ONLY your my.name@gmail.com account.

Comment: This is not a security issue in the slightest. When performing the "send mail as" procedure, Google verifies that you have access to the account in question by having you receive and enter a verification code. It could instead have you input your other account's login details. In any case, Google knows that you have access to that other account; you could just log in and send emails from there, or use a desktop client, and have no Sender header.