# How do I remove "sent by" in Google Apps Gmail aliases?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to change my email address to a different domain and Google Apps says I shouldn't need to change my primary domain name for this and that I can use a domain alias instead.

Unfortunately this is what shows up for people receiving my email.

[image]

Is anybody aware of a method that would only show my initial email address?

Comment: Have you seen this [older answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92324/117311)? Is it of any help to you? Or is it something different that you ask for?

Comment: Google Apps mentions many times on their website that it's almost never needed to change your primary domain, but it does seem there is no way around it in my case.

Comment: I am aware of that. Still. Should your question be marked as a duplicate or should I give it an answer here? It is always good for users to have an answered question they can refer to.